# Drag and drop batch file equivalent in Linux

Tags: python, linux, shell, batch-file, drag-and-drop

I am currently able to run files through my python script via a .bat file. The contents of this batch file is simply:

```
C:\Python26\python.exe mypythonfile.py %1
pause
```

I can drag and drop various files onto the .bat file and the python script will execute, using the dropped file as the argument...using sys.argv

This is fine for windows. But what I want to do now, is do the equivalent in Linux.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I've checked nautilus on GNOME desktop and it does not currently support passing files dropped as parameters to an script, even if encapsulated in a desktop file.

Comment: The answer would be specific to the desktop environment you use.

Answer (score 2):

the equivalent of your script on a `bourne compatible shell` (like `bash`, `dash`, `zsh` and most other shells you ever find on linux) would be:

```
#!/bin/sh
python /path/to/my/pythonfile.py $1
read
```

in practice this is not really needed, as for drag-n-drop you would create an application "shortcut" on your desktop that simply contains `python /path/to/my/pythonfile.py $1` as the application string. and be done with it.

the really clean solution would even add the shebang `#!/usr/bin/python` to the top of your .py-file and make it executable - so you can run it directly as

```
/path/to/my/pythonfile.py $1
```

integrating the script with your GUI (icon, where you can drop things at), is depending on the actual desktop environment you use.

### xfce4

create a new launcher (e.g. *right-click* on a panel, "add new element", choose *Starter*; then right click on the newly created Starter-Icon, click on "add new object", give it a name and in the cmdline-field add

```
/full/path/to/my/script.sh %U
```

the `%U` will be replaced with whatever you drop on the icon.

Comment: hmmm... I must be missing something. I have tried both ways. Creating a .sh file with #!/bin/sh
Python mypythonfile.py $1

Comment: ... and tried adding #!/usr/bin/env python to the top of my python file... neither seem to allow me to drag and drop

Comment: @iGwok first make sure that the script is working correctly: start a terminal and run it manually as `./myscript.sh /path/to/dropped/file` (assuming that you named your script `myscript.sh` and that you have the absolute path to the file you want to "drop")

Comment: ok so I opened Terminal and dragged the .sh file, followed by the dragdrop (argument) file, hit enter and got the error: /bin/sh^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

Comment: it seems that you created your script with notepad (or something else on w32), so it doesn't have the correct line endings. create your script with a text-editor that uses LF as lineendings (virtually any on linux, but some are intelligent and will kepp the current line-endings)

Comment: ok, the script is working :D but it is still not drag droppable. I am currently dragging mypythonfile.py into terminal (which has the shebang #!/usr/bin/env python on the 1st line), then I am dragging the argument file into Terminal and hitting enter. Success! Is it possible to have this drag droppable, so that I can just drag the argument file onto the python file, or something similar? Thanks for all you help btw!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a separate script if you start your python file with something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

Then you can simply drag & drop things on the python script itself.