# Pass a file as an argument in Linux

Tags: python, linux

I have a python script which take's a file as an argument via sys.argv.

What is the best way for passing this file as an argument in Linux?

I have tried adding this line of code on the 1st line of my python script, thinking that this would enable me to drag and drop files onto it, but this does not seem to work.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

Is there something I am missing? Cheers

Comment: umm did you try typing `python script.py filename` in the terminal?

Comment: Have you made the script eXecutable?

Comment: Does that binary path exist? (since it has a space)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19978540/drag-and-drop-batch-file-equivalent-in-linux suggests this depends on your desktop environment. (The "best" way is probably mu's suggestion, although that doesn't address drag and drop...)

Comment: Thanks mu... this is working... (face palm). Is this line of code necessary then? (#!/usr/bin/env python) and what is it for?

Comment: that line (which i don't think it's well-written) specifies a default binary so when you run the command: ..$ myscript.py, that python interpreter will be run

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `python script.py filename`

The line `#!/usr/bin/env python` is the shebang line.

If you make your script an executable one (that is, change it's file permission to executable using `chmod`), the shebang helps identify the type of script.

An alternate shebang would be to use the path for `python` binary directly like `#!/usr/bin/python`, but the path may differ on different machines and hence we normally get the path for the bindary from the `env`.

The shebang is not normally required if you are ok running the script everytime with `python script.py`, but if the script is referenced elsewhere, it might cause issues. I add a shebang to all my scripts just to be sure what script it is from within my editor.

Note that the the extension `.py` is entirely optional, and for sake of generality, you might want to run `./script` in bigger projects to achieve a task; this modularity ensures that the executable script can be in python, bash, or any other scripting language as long as it does what its supposed to do.

No, you can't drag and drop a file and pass it as a param to the python script even if it is an executable one.

Comment: Thanks... so if i make the script executable, I should be able to drag files onto it? or not?

Comment: No, you won't be able to.

Answer (score 5):

This is a pretty basic example that takes the first argument (sys.argv[1]), which we will assume is a filename, opens it, and prints all of the lines.

```
import sys

f = open(sys.argv[1])
lines = f.readlines()

for line in lines:
    print line

f.close()
```

You would call this file by entering python

```
<source_file.py> <filename>
```

If my source file was called readMyFile.py and I wanted to read myFile.txt, I would type

```
python readMyFile.py myFile.txt
```

[python system](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.argv)

As for accomplishing the drag and drop, you could always put the Python call into a bash script and then pass the argument from the bash script to the python script. Take a look at [this stack overflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10393164/create-executable-bash-script-that-accepts-drag-drop) about this. Essentially, you would just make a bash script with this code in it.

```
#!/bin/bash
python <source_file.py> "$1"
```

or in my specific example...

```
#!/bin/bash
python readMyFile.py "$1"
```

It looks like you might have to accompany some of the above syntax with some code in a .desktop file. Check out this [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/52789/drag-and-drop-file-onto-script-in-nautilus) link